# Чи можна вживати слово "вогнеграй"?

Tags: вживання-слів, значення-слів

Нещодавно наткнувся на це слово на [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%BD):

> Випрошування цукерок «Частування чи шкода» , костюмовані вечірки,
>   святкові багаття, світильник Джека, ловлення яблук, святкові столи,
>   **вогнеграї**.

І дуже воно мені сподобалося, однак в СУМі я його не знайшов.

А тому у мене виникло два запитання:

1. Чи можна вживати це слово, наприклад у творах для ЗНО? Бо мені здається, що воно не перечить правилам українського словотвору (у нас є слово [водограй](http://sum.in.ua/s/vodoghraj)).
2. Що воно означає? Це звичайне вогнище чи щось інше?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можна, гадаю, вживати, оскільки сама украӥнська не забороняє і особливо не забороняла [наподібок](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE)) чи [новослівја](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%BC) ві творах.

А так, це [*феєрверк*](https://uk.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9&redirect=no). Гадаю, сє до кшталту: нїмецького *Feuerwerk*, анґліјського *Firework*. А південословјанського досвіду з [*vatromet*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vatromet) вжити ми не взмозі, оскільки [*вогнемет*](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82) — вже має власного иншого значіня. З најблизькішого хіба шчо є чесько-словацьке [*ohňostroj*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/oh%C5%88ostroj), де украӥнська має корня [*стріј*](http://sum.in.ua/s/strij) з подібним значіням. Однак слово *водограј*, пак словникового, надає перевазі *вогнеграю*.